# TinyMCE : ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tinymce

this my code for TinyMCE

```
   @model TinyEditorWithMVCApp.Models.Post


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddPost";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add new Post</h2>

<h2>Add new Post</h2>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TintMCE App</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "modern",
            plugins: "advlist,code,bbcode,hr,link,paste,save",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "center",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            forced_root_block: false,
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AuthorName)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body)
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Post" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result should be like this  :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuLx4.png)

and this is what i got after debug project[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHNYI.png)

what is the problem of my code ?

i checked console from my browser i got this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ4OC.png)

Comment: Open your browser's console and check for errors. The script block isn't valid javascript

Comment: please check i edit the Question , try to change some thing and got different result !

Comment: As the error says it can't load the script you wanted it to. Is it really at that location?

Comment: ok i solved it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shared what version of TinyMCE you are using but assuming you are using TinyMCE v5.x several options in your configuration are invalid.

Of most importance, there is no `modern` theme in TinyMCE 5 so this line is invalid:

```
theme: "modern",
```

TinyMCE will use its default theme automatically so you don't really need that line at all - you can just remove it.  While your error message is hard to read I believe the error you posted is that TinyMCE cannot load the non-existent `modern` theme.

All the settings that start with `theme_advanced_` are also not valid for TinyMCE 5 - those were last valid in TinyMCE 3.x.

Comment: I use last version of Tiny 5.2

Comment: I use last version of Tiny 5.2 so what is the invalid statement in my code?

Comment: You don't need to reference the theme at all in your configuration - if you don't ask for a specific theme you will get the default theme automatically.